# Ubuntu 16.10 running lightdm and i3 Disappearing Mouse Cursor

Tags: nvidia, mouse, 16.10, bug-reporting, i3-wm

I looked on Google and found a few solutions, but none seem to work.

I have a Onyx Pro from System 76. The only change I made was installing i3.

My mouse seems to disappear more when it's moving over videos in the browser, but this isn't confirmed.

I have tried both of the following:

1. `CTRL + ALT + F1` then `CTRL + ALT + F7` (to toggle to TTY1 and back)
2. `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false`

Both haven't worked, and these seem to be about the only solutions to this issue that I have seen, which is why I'm re-asking the question on a more recent version.

Versions:

`i3 version 4.12 (2016-03-06, branch "4.12")`

`lightdm 1.19.5`

`NVIDIA-SMI 375.26` [Entire output](http://gist.github.com/pachonk/33b84eb0ef7334ebe18d9fcf30a68323)

Comment: 16.10 was installed by you or upgraded, correct? You need to install drivers or re-enabled the System76 PPA after an online release upgrade: http://support.system76.com/articles/restore/ (Chapter 4)

Comment: It was installed by System76's team fresh.

Comment: Which Nvidia driver version?

Comment: `NVIDIA-SMI 375.26` Entire output: https://gist.github.com/pachonk/33b84eb0ef7334ebe18d9fcf30a68323